# How to separate two array by id

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array ,i want to seperate array into single array by there TNXID.by any php function seperate array by TXNID into one single array variable .Because i want to save array with parent TXNID and child TXNID save..My demo code is

```
Array
(
    [XYX] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [TXNObjectType] => 102
                    [CustomerAccountID] => 951
                    [ParentTXNLineNumber] => 1
                    [TXNID] => 11

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [TXNObjectType] => 84
                    [CustomerAccountID] => 951
                    [ParentTXNLineNumber] => 1
                    [TXNID] => 12

                )

        )

    [XYZ] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [TXNID] => 11
                    [LineNo] => 7
                    [BranchID] => 164

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [TXNID] => 11
                    [LineNo] => 8
                    [BranchID] => 164

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [TXNID] => 12
                    [LineNo] => 9
                    [BranchID] => 164

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [TXNID] => 12
                    [LineNo] => 10
                    [BranchID] => 164

                )

        )

)
```

Expected output:

```
Array(

   Array
    (
        [XYX] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [TXNObjectType] => 102
                        [CustomerAccountID] => 951
                        [ParentTXNLineNumber] => 1
                        [TXNID] => 11

                    )
       )
   )

   Array(
    [XYZ] => Array
           (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [TXNID] => 11
                        [LineNo] => 7
                        [BranchID] => 164

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [TXNID] => 11
                        [LineNo] => 8
                        [BranchID] => 164

            )
    )
)


Array(

   Array
    (
        [XYX] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [TXNObjectType] => 102
                        [CustomerAccountID] => 951
                        [ParentTXNLineNumber] => 1
                        [TXNID] => 12

                    )
       )
   )

   Array(
    [XYZ] => Array
           (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [TXNID] => 12
                        [LineNo] => 7
                        [BranchID] => 164

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [TXNID] => 12
                        [LineNo] => 8
                        [BranchID] => 164

            )
    )
)
```

so please suggest mi appropriate solution for this .

Comment: Please edit your question to include the desired outcome and the code you have used to attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Hello sir i updated my question . i add some code which i want into result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to give you an approach on how I would go about it. Here you need to take care of two keys while rearranging the nested arrays. First is the outer-most keys labelled `XYX`,`XYZ` and so on. Second is the key for the child array i.e. `TXNID`.

So, initially you could traverse the array and transform(flatten) it into this form:

```
 Array
( [0] => Array
            (
                [TXNObjectType] => 102
                [CustomerAccountID] => 951
                [ParentTXNLineNumber] => 1
                [TXNID] => 11
                [Parent] => XYX //Store the parent at the same level

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [TXNObjectType] => 84
                [CustomerAccountID] => 951
                [ParentTXNLineNumber] => 1
                [TXNID] => 12
                [Parent] => XYX //Store the parent at the same level
            )
      ...
```

Once you have this, you could simply sort this array of arrays based on the key `TXNID`. For that you might want to use [uasort](https://www.php.net/uasort). You will have to define a custom comparator for this, should be a fun exercise.

Once you have sorted the array of arrays. You will just have to traverse this array one last time and sort of uncompress it, by checking the `Parent` key and pushing in array elements with that as the `key` and the sorted arrays as the values to get back a nested output like you desire.

There [several](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) other `array` functions in `PHP` that might come in handy. This might not even be the most efficient solutions but I hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: I would appreciate if you try to code it yourself first and then improve upon it. I will try to explain you my approach if you tell me where I was unclear.